# Proof that the cofinality of the least worldly cardinal is $\omega$

Tags: logic, set-theory, model-theory, large-cardinals

Prove in $\text{ZFC}$ that if there is some ordinal $\alpha$ with $V_\alpha \models \text{ZFC}$, then $\text{cf}(\beta)=\omega$ where $\beta$ equals the least such $\alpha$.

Here is what I came up with.

> Suppose that $\text {cf}(\beta)>\omega$. Then $|V_{\beta}|> \aleph_0$.
>
> Apply the Lowenheim-Skolem theorem (L-S) to get an elementary
>   substructure $E_0 \preceq V_{\beta}$ where $|E_0|=|V_{\omega}|$. Then
>   there is some least $b_0 < \beta$ such that $E_0\subset V_{b_0}$.
>
> Apply L-S again to get $V_{b_0}\subset E_1 \preceq V_{\beta}$ where
>   $|E_1|=|V_{b_0}|<|V_{\beta}|$. We can find some least $b_1<\beta$ such
>   that $V_{b_1}\supset E_1$. Continuing like this,
>   we get $E_0\subset V_{b_0}\subset E_1 \subset V_{b_1}\subset E_2
>  \subset \cdots $, with $E_i\preceq V_{\beta}$ for  each $i\in \mathbb
>  N$. Then $\bigcup_n E_n = \bigcup_n V_{b_n} = V_{\sup\{b_n\}}$. As
>   $E_i \models \text{ZFC}$ for each $i$, it follows that
>   $V_{\sup\{b_n\}} \models \text{ZFC}$.

The problem is that I'm not sure how to justify that at each point in the chain (after the first), we can find a $V_{b_i}$ that contains $E_i$. I think it's true but am not sure and can't give a rigorous argument. I would appreciate any help.

Comment: Read your title again. :)

Comment: You did notice that I already changed it, and that your new edit made it weird again. Right? I'm gonna leave it for you to change the title to a proper one now.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Sorry haha, didn't look at the edit

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're correct that this is not clear that you can find such $\beta_i$, since who's to say that $E_i$ is bounded below $\beta$?

But you can solve this by going a similar but slightly different route: Reflection.

Since $V_\beta$ is a model of $\sf ZFC$, the reflection theorem holds for it, and note that the von Neumann hierarchy of $V_\beta$ is made of actual $V_\alpha$'s and not just parts of them. Now by induction reflect the first $n$ axioms of $\sf ZFC$ on higher and higher ordinals. By the fact we do this *in* $V$, there is no confusion with meta-theoretical issues (namely, the meta-theory of $V_\beta$ is $V$ itself), and by uncountable cofinality we can find a limit point where all $\sf ZFC$ axioms are reflected.

Therefore if $\beta$ had uncountable cofinality, it wasn't the first.

Comment: I get the idea, but could you please spell out the induction a bit for me?

Comment: Enumerate ZFC as $\varphi_n$, set $\alpha_0=0$ and now find $\alpha_{n+1} > \alpha_n$ for which $V_{\alpha_{n+1}}$ reflects $\varphi_0,\dots, \varphi_n$.